# Music player sometimes skips all songs and won't play

Tags: music, iphone, ios

I have a problem on my iPhone 5s (running iOS 10).

Sometimes my music player doesn't play music and just skips all of my songs, but after I reset my iPhone, it works well again.

At first I thought this was just a regular crash, but as this problem became more frequent, it's become annoying to me.

Is this a bug on iOS 10 or does my iPhone have a problem?

Comment: Is your music player the built-in Music app or did you download another one? Comment back `@owlswipe` so I can help you more.

Comment: @owlswipe i use built in Music app

Comment: OK, thanks. Another question: do you have a monthly subscription to Apple Music or are you listening to music you've purchased through iTunes?

Comment: @owlswipe i'm listening to my purchased music

Comment: Have you read the answers here—http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196879/why-is-my-itunes-music-app-suddenly-skipping-every-track

Comment: Also check out this forum—https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7666313?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @owlswipe thank you !! looks like the answer from apple forum is answer my question. i will try it first :)

Comment: You're welcome—let me know if it works.

Comment: @owlswipe i have tried to prove discussions.apple.com/thread/7666313?start=0&tstart=0 that said this problem only occurred when using shuffle feature, but it appear that even when i'm not shuffled my songs, this still happen to me. And when i read again that discussion, looks like this is a problem since iOS 10.0 and still not fixed

Comment: Hmm! I guess just contacting Apple is your best bet here: https://getsupport.apple.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that was fixed in iOS 10.3. My Music app started behaving as expected after I updated my iPhone.